# When sheafification functor is open

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies, categorical-logic

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a Grothendiek topos and let $(\mathcal{C},J)$ be a site for $\mathcal{G}$.

> Is it true that if the sheafification functor $$ \mathcal{G} \leftrightarrows \text{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}} $$ is open then it is an equivalence of categories?!

---

I have just a very intuitive idea to prove this conjecture. Suppose that $(\mathcal{C},J)$ is a locale with enough points. Call $D$ the trivial topology over $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\text{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}} = \text{Sh}(\mathcal{C},D)$. Then we are just asking to the identity map $$\text{Points}(C,D) \to \text{Points}(C,J) $$ to be open and continous. Of course now, $J$ must be the trivial topology.

Comment: Your conjecture states that any open subtopos of a presheaf topos is equivalent to that presheaf topos. That's not true, as Andrea explained. A simple counterexample is provided by the empty subtopos, which is always an open subtopos (it is given by the modal operator $\nabla$ with $\nabla\varphi \equiv (\bot \Rightarrow \varphi)$). The [nLab page on open subtoposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/open+subtopos) might be helpful; I'll record this comment there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lemma 1.4 of *Open maps of toposes* by P. T. Johnstone (cf. [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01303275.pdf) or on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/open+subtopos#properties)), the sheafification functor is open if and only if $\mathcal G$ is an open subtopos of $\widehat{C}$, i.e. if and only if there exists a subterminal object $U \to e_{\widehat{C}}$ such that $\mathcal G$ is equivalent to $\widehat{C}/U \simeq \widehat{C/U}$, where here $e_{\widehat{C}}$ is the terminal presheaf on $C$ (cf. also the pertaining Stack Project page [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08LT)).

Now, a subterminal object of the presheaf topos $\widehat C$ is precisely a sieve of $C$, that is a full subcategory $S$ of $C$ such that if an object $c$ of $C$ belongs to $S$, than any arrow of $C$ with target $c$ is in $S$, as well. Therefore as long as the category $C$ is non-trivial you get a great number of open subtopoi of $\widehat C$, which correspond to the Lawvere-Tierney topologies on $\widehat{C}$ canonically induced by the subterminal object $U$, and they are equivalent to presheaves topoi of the form $\widehat S$, where $S$ is the sieve of $C$ associated to the subterminal object $U$ of $\widehat C$.